# Do we imagine the World?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language

If yes, please elucidate what must be the **case** such that we can make the statement : "We *imagine* the World".

If no (or if the question is meaningless/absurd) please demonstrate using logical arguments that it cannot be said that "We *imagine* the World".

Of course, I am not saying that we imagine trees or people or other physical objects. They indeed exist. What I am concerned about is the mental accounting of these things.

Answer (score 1):

I can make a reasonable argument that (say) hammers do not exist in the world. This isn't to suggest that the wooden handle and steel head do not have solid, material form. Instead, I mean that a hammer is primarily a conceptual object, defined by and enmeshed in a set of human social practices that have no correlates in the physical world. A hammer *qua* hammer does not exist for an ant, or a lemur, or a wallaby, even if they trip over one, because they do not grasp the functional nature of the tool as defined by humans.

Imagine you land on an alien world and find this *thing*: sort of a cube, with wavy edges and a few odd, rounded projections. It looks like it might have been constructed, but whatever it was within that alien worldview is lost (unless a friendly passing alien stops to explain it). Whatever it was to the aliens, it is not that to you, because you cannot *imagine* it in the way the aliens did.

Most of the human world is composed of things that we have imagined into existence because we find them useful, pleasant, convenient, or etc. Cars, spandex, pasteurized milk, chihuahuas, computers, congresspeople, bricks, chess boards: none of these would exist or have meaning except that we imagined them to be so, and worked to give them reality and meaning. Of course, this doesn't mean we can just focus our mind like some psychic superhero and #POP#: there's something we imagined into existence. But we cannot discount how much of the world we take as solid and real is nothing more than a shared conceptual construct we have imagined for ourselves.